# Пунктуация при прямой речи, случай с "говорят"

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант пунктуации более корректный.

> 1) Мне кажется, когда говорят: «Мысль материальна!» - имеют в виду
>   другое.
>
> 2) Мне кажется, когда говорят «Мысль материальна!», имеют в виду
>   другое.

Answer (score 2):

**Мне кажется, когда говорят: «Мысль материальна!» ― имеют в виду другое.**

Формально выбор тире, а не запятой можно объяснить наличием **восклицательного знака** в прямой речи.

С другой стороны, в  предложении такой структуры желательно поставить тире и сделать паузу даже при отсутствии восклицательного знака.

Сравнить:

*Мне кажется, когда говорят: «Мысль материальна», **то** имеют в виду другое.*

*Мне кажется, когда говорят: «Мысль материальна» ― имеют в виду другое (нет указательной частицы).*

Answer (score 2):

У меня вызывает сомнение сам подход. К чему здесь цитата, автор которой не указан? Разве принципиально необходимо это дословное цитирование? Куда естественней, на мой взгляд, выглядит такое предложение:

**Мне кажется, когда говорят, что мысль материальна, имеют в виду другое.**

Comment: Да, я бы тоже так написала. Такая пунктационная трактовка, как мне кажется, и проще, и понятнее.